# Javax Mail fetching is very slow

Tags: java

```
final Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(new Properties());

        try (Store store = session.getStore("imaps"))
        {
            store.connect("smtp.gmail.com", "email@gmail.com", "password");

            try (Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox"))
            {
                inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

                for (final Message message : inbox.getMessages())
                {
                    final Multipart multipart = (Multipart) message.getContent();

                    System.out.println(multipart.getBodyPart(0).getContent());
                }
            }
        }
```

The fetching of each mail takes around 0.5 second.
So if i do a loop over all my mail and let's say i have around 100 it can take up to minutes. Is there something wrong with my code or the javaxmail works like that? I realise it open a connection per mail but this seem wrong. It should fetch all data once and then cache them.

Comment: I had a similar issue when I first learned to use Java Mail and I was able to fix it. I just can't remember how. If I find my old code, I will share what I did.

Comment: If I remember correctly, I followed these recommendations. I just can't remember, but you may want to read this and try: https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/2354385/best-performance-method-for-retrieving-all-messages-on-imap-server